# angular function not called from ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

Can someone tell me why the logUserIn() function is not called on ng-click ??
This drives me crazy ???

In login.html there is a button with ng-click to logUserIn() function in loginController but it is impossible to get the function in action ????

1) app.module.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
       .module('czo',['ui.router'])
})();
```

2) app.route.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('czo')
        .config(config);

function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    // States
    $stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            url:'',
            views : {
                "bodyView": { templateUrl: "/cz-office/client/app/components/auth/login.html"},
                "footerView" : { templateUrl: "/cz-office/client/app/common/templates/footer.html"}
            }
        });
    };
})();
```

3) index.html (in root dir)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="czo">
<head>
   <title>Cool-Zawadi Back Office Application</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <base href="http://www.cool-zawadi.com/cz-office/">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
   <meta name="description" content="The cool-zawadi Back Office application">
   <meta name="author" content="Rudi Werner">
   <!--    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico"> -->
   <!-- Load jquery  -->
   <script src="/cz-office/client/app/assets/libs/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js">     </script>
   <!-- Load angular -->
   <!-- <script src="/cz-office/client/app/assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script> -->
   <!- In development we use the non minified version to have readable error messages -->
   <!- Change to angular.min.js in productuon -->
   <script src="/cz-office/client/app/assets/libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="/cz-office/client/app/assets/libs/angular/ui-router/ui-router.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cz-office/client/app/assets/css/czo.css">

<!-- Load personal scripts -->
<script src="/cz-office/client/app/app.module.js"></script>
<script src="/cz-office/client/app/app.routes.js"></script>
<script src="/cz-office/client/app/components/auth/loginctrl.js"></script>

</head>
{{ 2 +2 }}
<header>
   <div ui-view="headerView"></div>
</header>
<body>
   <div ui-view="bodyView"></div>
</body>
<footer>
   <div ui-view="footerView"></div>
</footer>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

4) login.html

```
<div ng-controller="loginCtrl as vm">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    {{3+3}}
    {{vm.test}}
    <label for="username">E-mail</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" ng-model="vm.username" required />
    <label for="password">Paswoord</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" ng-model="vm.password" required />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.logUserIn()">Login</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

5) loginctrl.js

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('czo')
    .controller('loginCtrl',loginCtrl);
function loginCtrl(){
    //variabelse
    var vm = this;
    vm.logUserIn = logUserIn;
    vm.test = 'DIT IS EEN TEST';
    console.log('Voor Functie');
    // functions
    function logUserIn(){
        console.log('in functie');
    };
};
})();
```

Comment: could you change function logUserIn() to vm.logUserIn = funcion() edit: in loginctrl.js

Comment: I tried this already but the same result !

Comment: The rest of the loginctrl is working though?

Comment: Yes the rest of the controller is working vm.test is displaying correct !

Comment: So when you say the change to vm.logUserIn = function() {} doesn't work - are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: No nothing in console

Comment: try it with an explicit reference to the scope, (e.g. add an parameter called `$scope` and add the the function to that).

Comment: Same result does not work ???? this drives me crazy ???

Comment: works for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/iuHSGWdyhMpRvRXxcdyI?p=preview

Comment: your plunker is not loading ? can you please email me your code ? rudi.werner@pandora.be thanks !

Comment: When i use your type of code in my testproject it is still not working possible that it has something to do with the ui-router or the 2 views ????

Answer (score 2):

you need to add logUserIn to the controller's scope: `vm.logUserIn = logUserIn`.

EDIT:

In your controller. You're just declaring a local variable in your `loginCtrl` called `logUserIn`, equivalent to just saying `var logUserIn = function(){ ... }`. Now that you've created the function, you need to add it to the controller's scope (`this` or `vm`).

Try declaring the controller like this:

```
angular.module('czo').controller('loginCtrl', function($scope) {
  //variabelse
  $scope.logUserIn = logUserIn;
  $scope.test = 'DIT IS EEN TEST';
  console.log('Voor Functie');
  $scope.logUserIn = logUserIn;
  // functions
  function logUserIn() {
    console.log('in functie');
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you give a littel bit more info please ? where must i place this ?

Comment: I just change my code but it is still not working ! see changes in code above !

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem was and it is very strange to me ?????

All my paths started at /cz-office/client/app....

And all files where found (no errors in console variabeles are recognized but function was not working)

After a couple hours of debugging i tyed wtih all files in same directory and function was working -> put back in different dirs and... whoops not working !

Some more debug and...

Then i change my path to client/app.....

And... everything is working !!!!!

The strange thing and what i not understood is that in both methods the files where retrieved and that in the previous situation only the function does not work ???